# Lawnmower stopping after ten minutes

Tags: electric-motor, lawn-mower

I am using an electric, battery-driven lawnmover of type Husqvarna LC 247iX. It is about one year old and was not used very much so far. The problem is that after ten minutes of operation the engine shuts down. The battery works well in other devices.

What could be the problem? Any hints how to fix this?

Comment: Air vents blocked? Battery too hot? Are other devices drawing same power as lawnmower?

Comment: Have you contacted Husqvarna about warranty service? I'd imagine that a large item like that would have a minimum 1-year warranty, hopefully more.

Comment: @SolarMike The other devices need less power.

Comment: @FreeMan Good point.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly contact the manufacturer as suggested.

If it runs for 10 minutes and stops, **and you don't charge the battery**, and you come back in an hour or a day and it runs for 10 minutes again, the likely issue is thermal/overheat - something is not being cooled properly - possibly a vent plugged with grass clippings.

If it runs for 10 minutes and stops, and you pop out the battery and **immediately** use it in something else (that works with that battery, right out of the mower right after the mower stopped,) probably the battery is not what's overheating. To prevent fires, Lithium-ion batteries do have thermal cutouts, and it's possible that some interaction of battery aging and the power draw of the mower might be overheating the battery and causing it to shut down. Otherwise suspect that the mower motor is overheating, where a vent full of grass clippings; mouse, spider, or wasp nests bulit over the winter in storage, or some such thing is the likely culprit.

If it needs to be charged to work again, back to battery aging effects, but different effects.

Comment: Thank you! I´ll check these things out.